# JavaFx "--add-module" in Java 8 (gradle)

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I try to get a working distribution of my Intellij- JavaFX- Project. In my gradle file I have:

```
compileJava {
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = [
                '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
                '--add-modules', 'javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.media'
        ]
        println options.compilerArgs
    }
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'
}
```

I added the `targetCompatibility` because when normal user install Java, they get Java 8. But when I try to build the program now, I get

```
Cause: error: option --add-modules not allowed with target 8
```

How can I add the javaFX modules without switching to Java 1.9?

Comment: Modules do not exist in Java 8.  They were introduced in Java 9.  And in Java 8, you don’t need to add anything;  JavaFX is part of regular Java SE 8.  So your entire `doFirst` block is not needed.

Comment: @VGR write that as an answer nad I accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules do not exist in Java 8. They were introduced in Java 9. And in Java 8, you don’t need to add anything; JavaFX is part of regular Java SE 8. So your entire `doFirst` block is not needed.